# How can I serve Laravel project on nginx on macOS?

Tags: laravel, nginx

I created Laravel project with `sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel MyProject --prefer-dist` command in "/Users/vala/Documents/laravel/" directory. Then I ran these commands:

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www /Users/vala/Documents/laravel/MyProject/
sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/vala/Documents/laravel/MyProject/
```

Then I create a file called "laravel" in "/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/" and write text below in it:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  root /Users/vala/Documents/laravel/MyProject/public;
  index  index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name  mylaravelproject.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;        
  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_index            index.php;
     fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
     include                  fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
     fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

}
```

Then I ran `sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/laravel /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and after that I ran these commands:

```
launchctl unload /usr/local/cellar/nginx/1.17.8/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
launchctl load /usr/local/cellar/nginx/1.17.8/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

But when I open "mylaravelproject.com" on my browser it shows **This site can’t be reached**.

I'm using MySQL database.

What did I miss?

Comment: I would suggest to use valet . It will run your application in breeze

Comment: "Project doesn't shouw up" — What output do you get?

Comment: @sh1hab valet is best for mac + laravel

Comment: did you setup your hostname correctl? If this is just for local testing you need to set up an entry in your hosts (`/etc/hosts`?) to point mylaravelproject.com to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to run a laravel project in Mac NginX, but we need to write a bit of code to make the laravel's url rewrite functions. Here is the nginx conf file for your reference.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /Users/vala/Documents/laravel/MyProject/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

include servers/*;
}
```

then restart the nginx server.

`nginx -s reload`

Comment: Where nginx.conf file is located?

Comment: its wont be nginx.conf, it will be like default.conf or sitesname.conf

Answer (score 0):

Manually setting up a local environment can be time consuming. To help you clarify your question here is a list of considerations:

1. Have you setup php-fpm service? Is it running?
2. Have you added redirection in /etc/hosts file for your example.com?
3. What database will you be running? Is it installed and running?

My suggestion is to use Docker with Laradock as it is simple to use and you can choose to use Laradock in production to sync up both development and production environments, official page is here [laradock.io](https://laradock.io/)

Comment: No, I haven’t  setup php-fpm service and I haven't added redirection in /etc/hosts file and I'm running MySQL database.